# Complete row within a data frame according to another df in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame such as :

**`DF1`**

```
COL1 COL2 COL3
sp1  1    A
sp1  2    B
sp1  3    C
sp1  4    D
sp2  2    E
sp2  4    F
sp3  1    G
sp3  2    H
sp3  4    I
sp3  5    J
```

and another data frame such as ;

**`DF2`**

```
COL2
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

and I would like to add missing `COL2 values` for each **COL1 value** within the **DF1**.

I should then get :

```
COL1 COL2 COL3
sp1  1    A
sp1  2    B
sp1  3    C
sp1  4    D
sp1  5    NA
sp1  6    NA
sp1  7    NA
sp1  8    NA
sp2  1    NA
sp2  2    E
sp2  3    NA
sp2  4    F
sp2  5    NA
sp2  6    NA
sp2  7    NA
sp2  8    NA
sp3  1    G
sp3  2    H
sp3  3    NA
sp3  4    I
sp3  5    J
sp3  6    NA
sp3  7    NA
sp3  8    NA
```

Here are the df in dput format :

*df1*

```
structure(list(COL1 = c("sp1", "sp1", "sp1", "sp1", "sp2", "sp2", 
"sp3", "sp3", "sp3", "sp3"), COL2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 5L), COL3 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", 
"H", "I", "J")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

**df2**

```
structure(list(COL2 = 1:8), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Did you try merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # crossing
df2 %>%
  crossing(COL1 = df1$COL1) %>%
  left_join(df1, by = c("COL1", "COL2"))
# # A tibble: 24 x 3
#     COL2 COL1  COL3 
#    <int> <chr> <chr>
#  1     1 sp1   A    
#  2     1 sp2   NA   
#  3     1 sp3   G    
#  4     2 sp1   B    
#  5     2 sp2   E    
#  6     2 sp3   H    
#  7     3 sp1   C    
#  8     3 sp2   NA   
#  9     3 sp3   NA   
# 10     4 sp1   D    
# # ... with 14 more rows
```

### base R

```r
eg <- expand.grid(COL1 = unique(df1$COL1), COL2 = unique(df2$COL2), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
merge(df1, eg, by = c("COL1", "COL2"), all = TRUE)
#    COL1 COL2 COL3
# 1   sp1    1    A
# 2   sp1    2    B
# 3   sp1    3    C
# 4   sp1    4    D
# 5   sp1    5 <NA>
# 6   sp1    6 <NA>
# 7   sp1    7 <NA>
# 8   sp1    8 <NA>
# 9   sp2    1 <NA>
# 10  sp2    2    E
# 11  sp2    3 <NA>
# 12  sp2    4    F
# 13  sp2    5 <NA>
# 14  sp2    6 <NA>
# 15  sp2    7 <NA>
# 16  sp2    8 <NA>
# 17  sp3    1    G
# 18  sp3    2    H
# 19  sp3    3 <NA>
# 20  sp3    4    I
# 21  sp3    5    J
# 22  sp3    6 <NA>
# 23  sp3    7 <NA>
# 24  sp3    8 <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `complete()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% group_by(COL1) %>% complete(df2)

   COL1 COL2 COL3
1   sp1    1    A
2   sp1    2    B
3   sp1    3    C
4   sp1    4    D
5   sp1    5 <NA>
6   sp1    6 <NA>
7   sp1    7 <NA>
8   sp1    8 <NA>
9   sp2    1 <NA>
10  sp2    2    E
11  sp2    3 <NA>
12  sp2    4    F
13  sp2    5 <NA>
14  sp2    6 <NA>
15  sp2    7 <NA>
16  sp2    8 <NA>
17  sp3    1    G
18  sp3    2    H
19  sp3    3 <NA>
20  sp3    4    I
21  sp3    5    J
22  sp3    6 <NA>
23  sp3    7 <NA>
24  sp3    8 <NA>
```

Comment: Very neat solution. Can you explain why it works with `complete(df2)`? Does it automatically mathc by column names, i.e. figures out that df2 only has COL2 and that there is a COL2 in df1 as well, so that's the only possible match?

Comment: Just theoretically, what if df2 would contain two columns: COL_2 (see the different name!) and COL_whatever?

Comment: The documentation of `tidyr::complete` says: "This is a wrapper around expand(), dplyr::full_join() and replace_na()", therefore yes, it automatically "complete" on intersecting column names. If `df2` does not contain a matching name with `df` or has multiple columns, you'll need to do `df1 %>% group_by(COL1) %>%  complete(COL2 = df2$COLLLLLLLLLLLLL2)`, where obvisously, `df2$COLLLLLLLLLLLLL2` contains the values `1:8`

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  full_join(df1 %>% expand(COL1, COL2 = df2$COL2), by = c("COL1", "COL2"))

   COL1 COL2 COL3
1   sp1    1    A
2   sp1    2    B
3   sp1    3    C
4   sp1    4    D
5   sp2    2    E
6   sp2    4    F
7   sp3    1    G
8   sp3    2    H
9   sp3    4    I
10  sp3    5    J
11  sp1    5 <NA>
12  sp1    6 <NA>
13  sp1    7 <NA>
14  sp1    8 <NA>
15  sp2    1 <NA>
16  sp2    3 <NA>
17  sp2    5 <NA>
18  sp2    6 <NA>
19  sp2    7 <NA>
20  sp2    8 <NA>
21  sp3    3 <NA>
22  sp3    6 <NA>
23  sp3    7 <NA>
24  sp3    8 <NA>
```

Comment: Curious, is there a reason you prefer (here) nested `%>%`-pipes instead of `df1 %>% expand(...) %>% full_join(df1, ...)`? I've always found nested pipes to have a higher chance of being visually confusing; this one is straight-forward, but the Inception of nested-`%>%` can get dizzying.

Comment: Completely agree that it‘s not an elegant solution. I basically trial & errored a bot and this one worked. But I‘d definitely prefer an unnested solution over this one.